# how add string contain left to right and right to left language to StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have confused with StringBuilder in java.
My code is here:

```
StringBuilder cmdB = new StringBuilder(
            "INSERT IGNORE INTO Query ( context, category, generality, freshness, TokenCount, type) VALUES ");
    for (int i = 0; i < querydata.size(); i++) {

        if (i == 0)
            cmdB.append("('");
        else
            cmdB.append(",('");
        cmdB.append(querydata.get(i).getContext() + "',"
                + querydata.get(i).getCategory() + ","
                + querydata.get(i).getGenerality() + ","
                + querydata.get(i).getFreshness() + ","
                + querydata.get(i).getTokenCount() + ","
                + querydata.get(i).getType());
        cmdB.append(")");
    }
    cmdB.append(";");
```

I have Mysql as database and want to create string that insert 1000 row. The querydata.get(i).getContext() return String and contain English(left ro right) and Persian(right to left language).

When my querydata.get(i).getContext() return "دانلود کرک بازی ghost recon" my Stringbuilder add it incorporated. My result show below.

INSERT IGNORE INTO Query ( context, category, generality, freshness, TokenCount, type) VALUES ('پخش زنده فوتبال',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),('عکسهای جشنواره فیلم فجر',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),('نتایج لیگ برتر',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),('دانلود کرک بازی ghost recon',2,1.0,0.0,2,1).

Comment: what MySql error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing actually wrong with the contents of the string in terms of *logical* order, as far as I can see, what may be confusing you is the way that the bidirectional text is being rendered when you print it.  If you drag your mouse over the string you can see by the way the selection jumps around which runs of text are being rendered with which predominant directionality.

If I separate the sets of values with newlines I get

INSERT IGNORE INTO Query ( context, category, generality, freshness, TokenCount, type) VALUES
('پخش زنده فوتبال',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('عکسهای جشنواره فیلم فجر',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('نتایج لیگ برتر',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('دانلود کرک بازی ghost recon',2,1.0,0.0,2,1).

I'm not sure what you see in your browser but in mine it's treating the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` line as LTR, then the subsequent lines up to but not including the one containing `ghost recon` as predominantly RTL.  Here is the same string with Unicode left-to-right markers (`U+200E`) inserted around the Persian script parts, to force the surrounding quotes and brackets to be treated as LTR:

INSERT IGNORE INTO Query ( context, category, generality, freshness, TokenCount, type) VALUES 
('‎پخش زنده فوتبال‎',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('‎عکسهای جشنواره فیلم فجر‎',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('‎نتایج لیگ برتر‎',2,1.0,0.0,2,1),
('‎دانلود کرک بازی‎ ghost recon',2,1.0,0.0,2,1).

In other words - don't worry, the database will contain the right thing.

But I also agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101369/592139) that you should consider using `PreparedStatement` instead of building SQL with a `StringBuilder`, to protect against SQL injection attacks (or obscure errors) in case any of your context strings contain apostrophes (which happens more often than **you'd** think).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking in your question but you should really consider using a batch insert tool to do such large inserts.  It will be better on memory, speed, and security.    Check out SpringSource's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and it's [batchUpdate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter%29) method.  Below is a simple examples taken from a google seach...

```
public void insertBatch(final List<Customer> customers){
 
  String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
    "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
 
  getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
 
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = customers.get(i);
        ps.setLong(1, customer.getCustId());
        ps.setString(2, customer.getName());
        ps.setInt(3, customer.getAge() );
    }
 
    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return customers.size();
    }
  });
}
```